# How to exclude all elements in Flux from another Flux

Tags: java, spring, stream, project-reactor

I have two `Flux`s one for successful elements another one holding the erroneous elements

```
Flux<String> success= Flux.just("Orange", "Apple", "Banana","Grape", "Strawberry");
Flux<String> erroneous = Flux.just("Banana","Grape",);
```

How can i filter the first `Flux` to execlude all the elements from the second one ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may wish to consider collecting the `Flux` into a set, caching that set, and then using `filterWhen` as follows:

```
Mono<Set<String>> erroneousSet = erroneous.collect(Collectors.toSet()).cache();
Flux<String> filtered = success.filterWhen(v -> erroneousSet.map(s -> !s.contains(v)));
```

Gives:

```
Orange
Apple
Strawberry
```

This isn't the most concise solution (see below), but it enables the contents of `erroneous` to be cached. In this specific example that's a moot point, but if it's a real-world situation (not using `Flux.just()`) then `erroneous` could be recomputed on every subscription, and that could end up being incredibly (and unnecessarily) expensive in performance terms.

Alternatively, if the above really doesn't matter in your use case, `filterWhen()` and `hasElement()` can be used much more concisely as follows:

```
success.filterWhen(s -> erroneous.hasElement(s).map(x->!x))
```

Or with reactor-extra:

```
success.filterWhen(s -> BooleanUtils.not(erroneous.hasElement(s)))
```

Comment: Just one word, Perfect

Comment: Ideally there would be a `hasNoElement()` or similar to avoid the final `map()` call, but that's the best way around it for now :-)

Comment: @MeladBasilius Just had a brainwave and updated with a slightly different alternative if you happen to have `reactor-extra` in place already. Not much point including it just for that though.

Comment: note that using a `Flux` for that purpose can be a bit inadapted if you have the opportunity to first collect the elements to exclude in a `set` and use `.filter(...)` instead. especially if `erroneous` is recomputed everytime it is subscribed to, and the `just` is for demonstration purpose only

Comment: @SimonBaslé That's a good point. I guess if the `Flux` is the only available source (assuming it terminates), then a better option might be collecting as a set and caching, i.e. `erroneousSet = erroneous.collect(Collectors.toSet()).cache()` and `success.filterWhen(v -> erroneousSet.map(s -> !s.contains(v)))` - would that make sense or is there a more concise way I've missed?

Comment: @SimonBaslé Thanks for the confirmation. I've rewritten the answer - I think it's all too easy to jump to the most concise solution otherwise without considering the performance impact (as I did when first writing that post!)