# Compare two flux

Tags: spring-webflux, couchbase, reactive, reactor, spring-data-couchbase

When I try to compare two flux obtained from reactive couchbase repository facing timeout issue. I am trying to get all the cars from vehicle collection.

```
Flux<Vehicles> vehicles = vehicleRepo.findAll();
 
Flux<Car> cars = carRepo.findAll();

cars.flatMap(car -> {

    vehicles.filter(vehicle -> vehicle.type.equals("car") && vehicle.id==car.id).map(vehicle -> {
                

    });
});
```

when I try to compare these two flux getting error "Query timed out while streaming/receiving rows"

Facing error "Query timed out while streaming/receiving rows"

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606601/how-to-exclude-all-elements-in-flux-from-another-flux

Answer (score 0):

A timeout occurred while retrieving rows from one of the queries.  Timeouts can be specified by overriding configureEnvironment() in your configuration class.